# Laravel 5.5 - Method paginate not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I don't know what's wrong, but here's my script at my AppController.

```
function getData () {
    $list_data = MyModel::all()->sortBy('id')->paginate(15);
    $count_data = $list_siswa->count();
    return view('pages.list', ['list' => $list_data, 'count' => $count_data]);
}
```

And here's my model

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    protected $table = 'students';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'class',
        'gender',
        'address'
    ];
}
```

Any idea? I think the problem is in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

You must paginate a database query not a collection, therefore you must user `orderBy` instead of combining `all` with `sortBy`, I have tested the below code and can confirm it works

```
function getData () {
    $list_data = MyModel::orderBy('id')->paginate(15);
    $count_data = $list_data->count();
    return view('pages.list', ['list' => $list_data, 'count' => $count_data]);
}
```